# What all should I know about std::unique_lock?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

From what I have understood, `std::unique_lock` is a kind of wrapper around the underlying `mutex` object so as to provide a *safer* implementation over using raw `mutex`es (e.g., end up in unlocked state if an exception is thrown or on destruction). Is this all `std::unique_lock` is for?

Try #1

```
std::mutex m;  // global 
void foo() {
  m.lock();
  // critical section
  m.unlock();
}
```

Try #2

```
std::mutex m;  // global 
void foo() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m);
  // critical section
}
```

Is Try #2 preferred over Try #1, and is this what `std::unique_lock` is for? Please provide some other examples where `std::unique_lock` may be desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, that's exactly what it's for, and why you should use it.**

It does go a *little* beyond the simple example you gave; the time-related stuff in particular would be complex to implement on your own, but you *could* do it. Ultimately, though, yes, it's a wrapper.

From [cppreference on `unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock):

> The class `unique_lock` is a general-purpose mutex ownership wrapper allowing deferred locking, time-constrained attempts at locking, recursive locking, transfer of lock ownership, and use with condition variables.